# Check the state of a blob copy in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I started a blob copy using Azure PowerShell...

How can I retrieve the state of that blob copy from the PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cb5e6c2e-a540-45af-8aeb-2395f94c69fa) gets the copy status of an Azure Storage blob.